# xlsxwriter intersect row and column formats

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm saving pandas `DataFrame` to Excel with `xlsxwriter`. First I'm adding some format to columns (change font, for instance). Then I want to change background color for some rows. But when I add `set_row` function, all my column's format is gone. Is there a way to combine it?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'test_data': [1,2,3,4,5]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

pd.core.format.header_style = None

data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['test']

font_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 10})

worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, font_fmt)

zebra = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'green'})

for index in range(5):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        worksheet.set_row(index+1, None, zebra)

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

This shall help:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'test_data': [1,2,3,4,5]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

pd.core.format.header_style = None

data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['test']

formatdict = {'font_name': 'Calibri', 'font_size': 10, 'font_color':'red'}
font_fmt = workbook.add_format(formatdict)

worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, font_fmt)

zebra = workbook.add_format(formatdict)
zebra.set_bg_color('green')

for index in range(1,6,2):
        worksheet.set_row(index, None, zebra)

writer.save()
```

Shall produce the following output:

[image]